# "The clojure executable isn’t on your ‘exec-path’" even though lein is on my exec-path (macOS)

Tags: clojure, cider

I have the following `exec-path` (according to `describe-variable`):

```
("/usr/local/bin/" "/usr/bin/" "/bin/" "/usr/sbin/" "/sbin/" "/usr/local/Cellar/emacs-plus/25.3/libexec/emacs/25.3/x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0/")
```

This is the `lein` executable path:

```
/usr/local/bin/lein
```

This is what happens when I run `cider-jack-in`:

```
The clojure executable isn’t on your ‘exec-path’
```

What gives?

Edit: (`cider-lein-command` is `lein`)

Comment: If I create a project with lein new and go into that project, it works.

Comment: what about cider-jack-in-command? https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/blob/master/cider.el#L288 maybe project-type isn't set to lein.

Comment: `cider-lein-command is a variable defined in ‘cider.el’.
Its value is "lein"`

Comment: Right, but it's looking for the clojure command, not the lein command. "clojure" is an executable that was introduced with the new cli tool: https://clojure.org/guides/deps_and_cli

Comment: Thanks for the help @Jonah B. Could you please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it :) ?

Comment: I get this problem if i do `restart` in the cider repl. How do I configure cider to use lein?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(from the comment)

Looks like cider is looking for the clojure command, not the lein command.  "clojure" is an executable that was introduced with the new cli tool:

https://clojure.org/guides/deps_and_cli

Comment: Yes so... 

I'm having the same problem. I swear I was able to use ClojureCLI with CIDER, but I'm in a new system, with new Emacs, and can't do that anymore.

I'm not interested on Lein.

Answer (score 7):

I would just like to build onto **Jonah Benton**'s answer, in response to **ackerleytng**'s question on how to configure cider to use lein instead:

To change cider build command from clojure to lein, set lein as the value for variable `cider-default-repl-command`.

For the emacs beginner, you can see and change a variable value with keys `C-h v`.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the project root folder, where shadow-cljs.edn resides and run `npm run watch` then you'll be prompted to install shadow-cljs, type y and hit enter (Ok to proceed? (y) y) to install.